# How to create table via trigger that name as one of data that inserted

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I want a trigger that creates a table when data is added to the table. The table name must be the name of entry that was inserted.

Example: when patient registers in the hospital a rows is inserted to the `paitientDetail`  table. The trigger must create table that has the patient's name.

Comment: which RDBMS are you using?  You tagged both MySQL and sql-server?  You really want a separate table for each patient?  That screams poor design.  You are going to run into issues having a separate table for each patient.

Comment: For the love of all that is good and holy, why are you doing this?  What is being stored in this patient name table?  Why can't you just have one table with all of the patients and use a foreign key?

Comment: You really need to review the design.  If a thought pops in your head to do something like this or to think something like this is a good idea, please smash your hand with hammer as a distraction from such nonsense.

Comment: I'm practicing several things here. With SQLServer & MySQL also.Those days I trying things with SQLServer 2008

Comment: What have you tried?  Really dude, the "paitent" shouldn't not have their own table.  You should have a table with a PK/FK relationship.

Comment: I have to add this as well: ***Do not do this***. Just don't.

Comment: Now I know why medical costs are so high.

Answer (score 3):

Before I answer this question, I have to preface by saying **this is a terrible idea**.  *Please do not create a new table for each patient.*  This is going to create many issues for you down the road.

For example if you have 100 patients, you would then have 100 tables. Then what are you going to do if you need to return data for every single patient...you will have a mess trying to do that.

In SQL Server should you want to perform this type of process, you can do this the following way:

**Sample Table**:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test](
    [id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

`Your Trigger` would use Dynamic SQL to retrieve the name from the Inserted data.:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.testTrg
   ON  dbo.test
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    declare @newtable varchar(50)
    set @newtable = (select quotename(name) from inserted)

    declare @sql varchar(max)

    set @sql = 'create table ' + @newtable + '
        ( 
            [id] [int] NOT NULL, 
            [newColumn1] [varchar](50) NOT NULL
        ) ON [PRIMARY]' 

    exec(@sql)

END
```

This trigger will create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[test1](
    [id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [newColumn1] [varchar](50) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

A much better design for patients would be the following. Have one Patient table then you would have additional tables as needed to include any additional details for the Patient:

```
Patient Table:
id int, -- PK
name varchar(50)

Doctor Table
id int, -- PK
name varchar(50)

Patient_Doctor table
p_id int,  -- PK -- FK to Patient Table
d_id int  -- PK  -- FK to Doctor Table
```

Comment: can I use of column value of table A as table name of table B ? [my full question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31945774/how-to-use-content-of-a-column-as-table-name-in-trigger)